# Erro 1215 MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, chave-estrangeira

**Primeiramente, gostaria de dizer que já verifiquei várias perguntas sobre isso por aqui e nenhuma solução funcionou.**

Estou dando alter table na tabela funcionario para adicionar duas foreign keys...uma delas funciona(num_departamento) mas a outra por algum motivo retorna o erro 1215.

Segue as queries:

```
alter table departamento
add num_sup int,
add num_departamento int,
add primary key(num_departamento,num_sup)

alter table funcionario
add num_sup int,
add num_departamento int,
add constraint fk_num_depart foreign key(num_departamento) references 
departamento(num_departamento),
add constraint fk_num_supr foreign key(num_sup) references 
departamento(num_sup)
```

Já tentei dropar a tabela e conferir os campos, entre outras soluções, mas nada funcionou...O que pode ser?

Segue a modelagem das tabelas.

[image: Modelagem das Tabelas]

Comment: Coloca a tabela departamento aí na pergunta.

Comment: Não adiciona, fica mais fácil de dar manutenção.

Comment: Adicionei a modelagem das tabelas(como elas devem ficar no fim) para ajudar.

Comment: A FK tem bater com a PK original alter table funcionario
add num_sup int,
add num_departamento int,
add constraint fk_num_depart_sup foreign key(num_departamento,num_sup) references 
departamento(num_departamento,num_sup)